# how to get date part in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

```
id  name date
1   AAA 12-01-15
2   BBB 19-09-12
3   CCC 23-07-10
4   DDD 06-10-01
5   EEE 08-11-05
6   FFF 18-04-99
7   GGG 07-08-12
```

i have  tried it but by converting it is possible but i dont want to convert it  i want to extract only date part help me out please

i have a table with date field with datatype  i want to extract date from date field

my condition is i want to get records which equal to sysdate i.e i want to get records which are inserted on present day which equal to datepart

Comment: You're a bit unclear. Do you have a DATE column or a date saved in a VARCHAR2 format?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly the 'date' column in your table has the DATE datatype. If so then the following should get what you're looking for:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
  WHERE TRUNC(t.DATE_FIELD) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)
```

Of course, based on the data in your question the above query will not return any rows, but if there was data in the table with the same date as SYSDATE they would be returned.

(And by-the-way - since DATE is a data type it's a Bad Idea to use it as the name of a column. Here I've changed it to `DATE_FIELD`).

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

If your column is `varchar`, then use this

```
select * from (
select '21-10-15' as dt from dual)
where to_date(dt,'dd-mm-yy') = trunc(sysdate)
```

If your column is on type `date` and you are storing only date, not timestamp, then use this.

```
select * From (
select to_date('21-10-15','dd-mm-yy') as dt from dual)
where dt = trunc(sysdate)
```

If you are saving the column as date along with time, then use Bob's solution

```
select * From (
select to_date('21-10-15','dd-mm-yy') as dt from dual)
where trunc(dt) = trunc(sysdate)
```

I changed the column to `dt`. Change it as per your convenience.

Comment: You should use `to_date(dt,'dd-mm-rr')` (or even better use four digits), otherwise `18-04-99` will be 2099-04-18!

Comment: np. And please accept the answer best suited for you by clicking on tick symbol on left of the answer so it could be closed. Thanks.